# AngularJS set synchronous call of function from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this directive :

```
app.directive('changemonth', function($animator) {
    return {
      link : function($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("click", function() {

          if(element.attr('class').search('disabled') == -1) {

            // récupération du calendrier :
            if(element.attr('class').search('day') != -1)
              var calendar = angular.element(element.parent().parent());
            else                                         
              var calendar = angular.element(element.parent().parent().next().children()[1]);
            var animator = $animator($scope, attrs);

            animator.hide(calendar); 
            setTimeout(function() { 
              $scope.$apply(attrs.changemonth);
              animator.show(calendar); 
            }, 500);
          }
        });
      }
    };
});
```

With `attrs.changemonth`, i call a function (wich can change), for exemple this one :

```
$scope.next = function() {
        var tmpMonth = $scope.monthsLabels.indexOf($scope.monthDisplayed) + 1;
        var tmpYear = $scope.yearDisplayed;
        if(tmpMonth==12) {
            tmpMonth = 0;
            tmpYear = parseInt($scope.yearDisplayed) + 1;
        }
        getCalendar(tmpMonth, tmpYear);
        $scope.monthDisplayed = $scope.monthsLabels[tmpMonth];
        $scope.yearDisplayed = tmpYear.toString();
    };
```

And so this function call another `getCalendar()` you can see here :

```
function getCalendar(month, year) {
        $http({
            method : "GET", 
            url : 'http://my_url/getCalendar', 
            params : { 
                group_id : $scope.group_id,
                month : month,
                year : year
            }
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.calendar = data;
        });
    }
```

`getCalendar()` use `$http` to get the calendar from database.

My problem is that i would like to wait for the response of `$http` before using animator in directive, like this, my calendar will only be displayed if the content is loaded.

I heard of `$q` and promises. But I don't see how to use it in this very particular context.

It would be awesome if somebody here have an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try broadcasting from your success callback like this.

```
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.calendar = data;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:calendar-received');
});
```

Then in your directive you can wait to receive that signal like this.

```
$scope.$on('event:calendar-received', function() {
    ... do your stuff with animator...
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it works parfectly and i needed just a very little changing.

Comment: I just have one problem now. As I have multiple calls of $scope.$on('event:calendar-received', function() {}, I can't make the differences between my differents calls. So the event launch sometimes with the parameters of the last $broadcast not the earliest. How could i make all $broadcast indepedent from each other ? thanks again for help.

Comment: OK, i just added some unique token to the $broadcast string and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`$http(...)` evaluates to a promise. That means that given

```
var x = $http(...)
```

You can do

```
x.then(function success(){...}, function failure(){...});
```

and the `success` or `failure` function will only be called when the promise is resolved. See the promise [API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q).

Your functions can return this `x` and their calling functions can interact with it as a promise.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i tried but it seems that something goes wrong. Technicaly your tip works but it doesn't works well with my other stuffs. Thanks again for the help.